# NPM license for open source

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on publishing a NPM package and want to keep it open source. In that case, what should I use for LICENSE ? By default it is set as

```
"license": "ISC",
```

what does that mean ?

Comment: What is an ISC License, is something you ask Google. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISC_license. What should I use? Is entirely up to you and otherwise opinion based. There are various forms of open source licence. Pick one.

Comment: To make sure your question isn't closed as opinion based, you may want to rewrite your question to indicate what you want the license to do, so that the question is more about what license is closest to what you want, right now, your requirement are "any open source license". If you wanted to know what ISC is above all, you may want to edit the question title.

Answer (score 1):

ISC stands for `Internet Systems Consortium`. It's an equivalent to MIT, you can use it for open-source project.

> Copyright YYYY User
>
> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 0):

Github have made a [nice human readable resume of the open source licenses](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/isc/) to make it a simple choice:

- You want it permissive above all? MIT
- You care about patents? Apache
- You want to be sure it will always be open source above all else? GNU GPL v3

ISC isn't [listed](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/), Zooly's answer suggest it is equivalent to MIT.